# Google Sheet - filter non-zero or #N/A using custom formula

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

Say my data is in range A6:Z with the headers in row 5. I want to display rows with value in column C that is non-zero or `#N/A`. I tried `OR(C6:C <> 0, IFNA(C6:C, true))` and `OR(C6:C <> 0, ISNA(C6:C))` and none of them works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
=INDEX(IF((IFNA(V6:V21))=0,,IFNA(V6:V21)))
```

[image]

To have just `0` values filtered out try

```
=INDEX(IF(V6:V21=0,,V6:V21))
```

Comment: Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Comment: I want to filter out only the 0 rows and keep the #N/A rows. If I use your method and apply NOT(ISBLANK(  )) to the result (column W), I miss out the #N/A rows.

Comment: So you want just `0` values filtered out. Yes?

Comment: Yes, only 0 values should be filtered out.

Comment: Please check the answer again. And don't forget to accept :)

Comment: Awesome. Thank you.